# How do I fix it so that it doesn't move the tank track when I'm rotating?

Tags: drivers

I made a base tank for the test which has the problem that if the tank turns, the track or move backward or move forward. Could this be make so that it does not move forward and backward the tank track when rotating the tank?  (I maked the movement of the tank track with the help of Driver.)

[image]